# Как записать комбинацию двух строк в одну строку?

Tags: python, python-3.x

У меня есть файл. Вот пример данных из файла:

```
10.000899
10.001798
10.002697
10.003596
10.004495
10.005394
10.006293
10.007192
10.008091
10.00899
10.009889
10.010788
10.011687
10.012586
10.013485
10.014384
10.015283
10.016182
10.017081
```

Мне надо пройтись по строкам и сохранить две соседние строки с одного файла в другой файл одной строчкой. 
Вариант записывать это все в список или массив не подойдет). 
Т. е. надо считывать данные и сразу их записывать в файл 
Должно быть что-то вроде:

```
10.000899 10.001798
10.001798 10.002697
10.002697 10.003596
10.003596 10.004495
10.004495 10.005394
```

Я пробовал использовать `enumerate`, но не могу понять как получить значение по индексу строки

```
with open("short_100.txt", "r") as fgfg, open("long_100.txt", "w"):
    for index, k in enumerate(fgfg):
```

По сути, задача сводится к тому, как получить номер строки по индексу строки, но пока не понимаю как это сделать. 
Как решить эту задачу?

Спасибо

Comment: Номер строки = индекс строки + 1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
with open('filename_in', 'r') as fin:
    with open('filename_out', 'w+') as fout:
        tmp = None
        for line in fin:
            if tmp is not None:
                fout.write(tmp + ' ' + line)

            tmp = line.rstrip('\n')
```

**UPD**: *если с шагом*

```
def write_file(f_in, f_out, line_step):
    with open(f_in, 'r') as fin:
        with open(f_out, 'w+') as fout:
            tmp = [None] * line_step

            index = 0
            for line in fin:
                if tmp[index % line_step] is not None:
                    fout.write(tmp[index % line_step] + ' ' + line)

                tmp[index % line_step] = line.rstrip('\n')
                index += 1


write_file('filename_in', 'filename_out', 5)
```

Comment: Ваш вариант отличный, удалю свой :)

Comment: @gil9red вам тоже за помощь спасибо)